# Which to answer - Which to close

Tags: discussion, answers, duplicate-questions, vote-to-close, merged-questions

Before 15 days, a user asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25527139/1771795) <sup>(1)</sup> which I had [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25545535/1771795) but I had to delete it because it was *incomplete*. The same user has asked the [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25600152/1771795) after deleting the first one.

A different user has asked exactly the [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25806683/1771795) and I have finally managed to find a *workaround*.

My question is, which post I should answer and which one I should close as duplicate?

<sup>(1) deleted by OP</sup>

Comment: if the questions are exactly the same, I would consider [flagging for moderator to merge](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/merged-questions/info). In this case, it wouldn't matter where to answer

Comment: @gnat never heard of that, nice feature, thanks for sharing! :)

Comment: @gnat I've flagged mod to merge questions, thanks again.

Comment: FWIW given that you have asked at meta, it would also help if you referred this very meta post in flag message. If you didn't, it's not critical, but in my experience, mods tend to appreciate this

Comment: @gnat great minds think alike ;)

Comment: @gnat I would suggest you post an answer with "merging questions", it looks like few users know this feature.

Comment: Omar, done as you suggested - [posted an answer with "merging questions"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271384/839601)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no need to retain at the site two identical copies of the same question. When (on-topic) questions are *exactly* the same, first thing to consider is flagging for moderator to [merge them](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/merged-questions/info):

> Questions that have been closed as duplicates may sometimes be merged by moderators.
>
> When questions are merged, both questions are retained (one will just be a stub) and all answers are migrated into the merged question. If the stub is deleted its URL will 301 redirect to the merge target.

As for where to put your answer, if you believe that questions should be merged, it doesn't really matter since all answers will be migrated into single question.

Answer (score 28):

For a case in which both candidate questions have no answers, I'd answer the question which is likely to be most understandable, most useful to future readers, etc. Basically, **I'd answer the question which is best written, and close the other one as duplicate.** There's no point in favoring an earlier question that is not as clear as the newer one, or that is badly written, or that is unlikely to be helpful to future readers.