# Is it OK to copy a good answer from an exact-duplicate question to the original question?

Tags: discussion, answers

Sometimes question A will have been marked as an exact-duplicate of question B, but will have an answer that is very good quality.

Would it be OK in that case to copy the answer from question A to question B, perhaps as a Community Wiki answer, so that this answer gains better visibility?

Comment: If the questions are exact duplicates, then the better solution would be to merge them.

Comment: @Yannis Doesn't that require you to be a moderator? What would I have to do to get a moderator to merge them?

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271384/839601

Comment: Yes, you'll need a moderator. Use the custom moderator flag, and clearly explain that you think the questions are exact duplicates and should be merged.

Answer (score 8):

Do not multiply answers by copying. Instead flag (and vote if possible) for it to be a duplicate or if it is an exact duplicate, flag for moderator attention and request a merge.